# how to create a set of group data and count detail in python

Tags: python, pandas, set

Current I suppose have data like this

```
data = {
'A': ['2023-07-01'] * 6 + ['2023-07-02'] * 5,
'data1': ['abnormal'] * 11,
'data2': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'A'],
'Data3': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110],
'Data4': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
}
```

[image]

Currently I did groupby A aggregation to count record, get distinct count, find distinct value

```
def create_set_ori(x):
return sorted(set(x))

result = df.groupby(['A']).agg({
  'data1': 'count',
  'data2': [pd.Series.nunique, create_set_ori]
  }).reset_index()

result.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in result.columns.values]
```

Which product result as

[image]

Now I want to upgrade  on create_set_ori function to provide additional information that count occurance detail event happen and sort the event counter as a format

(data2 , n) as well as sorting by n as well

for example

| A | data1_count | data2_nunique | data2_create_set |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-01 | 6 | 3 | [(X, 3), (Y, 2), (Z, 1)] |
| 2023-07-02 | 5 | 4 | [(Z, 2), (X, 1), (Y, 1), (A, 1)] |

I was wondering how can I archieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Let us use `Counter` from `collections` module

```
from collections import Counter

def create_set_ori(x):
    return [*Counter(x).most_common()]
```

---

```
           A_  data1_count  data2_nunique              data2_create_set_ori
0  2023-07-01            6              3          [(X, 3), (Y, 2), (Z, 1)]
1  2023-07-02            5              4  [(Z, 2), (X, 1), (Y, 1), (A, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think you want to import Counter from collections.

Counter will return a dict with the items as keys and the count as values.
So it will return:

```
{'x': 3, 'y': 2, 'z':1}
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).